# Is it possible to add an RSS feed using Ruby on Rails when you only have access to the .html? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, rss

I am currently using a very restrictive internal tool to build web-pages. I've been developing for a few years, but somehow have never worked with RSS feeds before.

As I am using this restrictive internal tool, it will only allow me to access the current .html file that I am editing - so no models, no views, no controllers - everything needs to be done in the .html.

I've been asked - using HTML, CSS, barebones JavaScript and inline Ruby on Rails to add a simple RSS feed to a web-page and style it up nicely. Most of the guides I have come across on the net suggest using an external server to parse the XML - unfortunately this is not possible in my case. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery plugin for this. plugin here http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html and https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed .